# How to start application and call method after scanning NFC Tag?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm new in NFC
and I'm trying to open my application by scanning the NFC tag and after it opened
I want the application call a method only if the application opened via the NFC.
I know how to write and read from the tag and open the application by scanning. But how do I can call method after the app is opened?
I used open source from the Internet and it is working for me pretty good.I would be happy if you set me how to do it correctly.
Here is the code:
Main:

```
public class PillowNfcSample extends ActionBarActivity {
    PillowNfcManager nfcManager;
    WriteTagHelper writeHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        nfcManager = new PillowNfcManager(this);
        nfcManager.onActivityCreate();

        nfcManager.setOnTagReadListener(new PillowNfcManager.TagReadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTagRead(String tagRead) {
                Toast.makeText(PillowNfcSample.this, "tag read:"+tagRead, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        writeHelper= new WriteTagHelper(this, nfcManager);
        nfcManager.setOnTagWriteErrorListener(writeHelper);
        nfcManager.setOnTagWriteListener(writeHelper);

        Button writeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.write_button);
        writeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = new Date().toString();
                writeHelper.writeText(text);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        nfcManager.onActivityResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        nfcManager.onActivityPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        nfcManager.onActivityNewIntent(intent);
    }

}
```

NfcManager:

```
 public class PillowNfcManager {
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
        Activity activity;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        TagReadListener onTagReadListener;
        TagWriteListener onTagWriteListener;
        TagWriteErrorListener onTagWriteErrorListener;

        String writeText = null;


        public PillowNfcManager(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the listener to read events
         */
        public void setOnTagReadListener(TagReadListener onTagReadListener) {
            this.onTagReadListener = onTagReadListener;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the listener to write events
         */
        public void setOnTagWriteListener(TagWriteListener onTagWriteListener) {
            this.onTagWriteListener = onTagWriteListener;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the listener to write error events
         */
        public void setOnTagWriteErrorListener(TagWriteErrorListener onTagWriteErrorListener) {
            this.onTagWriteErrorListener = onTagWriteErrorListener;
        }

        /**
         * Indicates that we want to write the given text to the next tag detected
         */
        public void writeText(String writeText) {
            this.writeText = writeText;
        }

        /**
         * Stops a writeText operation
         */
        public void undoWriteText() {
            this.writeText = null;
        }


        /**
         * To be executed on OnCreate of the activity
         * @return true if the device has nfc capabilities
         */
        public boolean onActivityCreate() {
            nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0,
                    new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
            return nfcAdapter!=null;
        }

        /**
         * To be executed on onResume of the activity
         */
        public void onActivityResume() {
            if (nfcAdapter != null) {
                if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    //TODO indicate that wireless should be opened
                }
                nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, null, null);
            }
        }

        /**
         * To be executed on onPause of the activity
         */
        public void onActivityPause() {
            if (nfcAdapter != null) {
                nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
            }
        }

        /**
         * To be executed on onNewIntent of activity
         * @param intent
         */
        public void onActivityNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Check if the following line has any use 
            // activity.setIntent(intent);
            if (writeText == null)
                readTagFromIntent(intent);
            else {
                Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                try {
                    writeTag(activity, tag, writeText);
                    onTagWriteListener.onTagWritten();
                } catch (NFCWriteException exception) {
                    onTagWriteErrorListener.onTagWriteError(exception);
                } finally {
                    writeText = null;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Reads a tag for a given intent and notifies listeners
         * @param intent
         */
        private void readTagFromIntent(Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                Tag myTag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                if (rawMsgs != null) {
                    NdefRecord[] records = ((NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0]).getRecords();
                    String text = ndefRecordToString(records[0]);
                    onTagReadListener.onTagRead(text);
                }
            }
        }

        public String ndefRecordToString(NdefRecord record) {
            byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
            return new String(payload);
        }


        public void clearTag(Tag tag){
            Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EMPTY, null, null, null)));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Writes a text to a tag
         * @param context
         * @param tag
         * @param data
         * @throws NFCWriteException
         */
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
        protected void writeTag(Context context, Tag tag, String data) throws NFCWriteException {
            // Record with actual data we care about
            NdefRecord relayRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_ABSOLUTE_URI, NdefRecord.RTD_URI, null, data.getBytes());

            // Complete NDEF message with both records
            NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
                    relayRecord,NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.mateuyabar.android.pillownfc")});

            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef != null) {
                // If the tag is already formatted, just write the message to it
                try {
                    ndef.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.unknownError);
                }
                // Make sure the tag is writable
                if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
                    throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.ReadOnly);
                }

                // Check if there's enough space on the tag for the message
                int size = message.toByteArray().length;
                if (ndef.getMaxSize() < size) {
                    throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.NoEnoughSpace);
                }

                try {
                    // Write the data to the tag
                    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
                } catch (TagLostException tle) {
                    throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.tagLost, tle);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.formattingError, ioe);// nfcFormattingErrorTitle
                } catch (FormatException fe) {
                    throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.formattingError, fe);
                }
            } else {
                // If the tag is not formatted, format it with the message
                NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
                if (format != null) {
                    try {
                        format.connect();
                        format.format(message);
                    } catch (TagLostException tle) {
                        throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.tagLost, tle);
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.formattingError, ioe);
                    } catch (FormatException fe) {
                        throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.formattingError, fe);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new NFCWriteException(NFCErrorType.noNdefError);
                }
            }

        }

        public interface TagReadListener {
             void onTagRead(String tagRead);
        }

        public interface TagWriteListener {
             void onTagWritten();
        }

        public interface TagWriteErrorListener {
             void onTagWriteError(NFCWriteException exception);
        }
```

Helper class:

```
 public class WriteTagHelper implements PillowNfcManager.TagWriteErrorListener, PillowNfcManager.TagWriteListener{
    AlertDialog dialog;
    PillowNfcManager nfcManager;
    Context context;
    int dialogViewId = R.layout.write_nfc_dialog_view;

    public WriteTagHelper(Context context, PillowNfcManager nfcManager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.nfcManager = nfcManager;
    }

    /**
     * Write the given text to a tag.
     * @param text
     */
    public void writeText(String text){
        dialog = createWaitingDialog();
        dialog.show();
        nfcManager.writeText(text);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTagWritten() {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.tag_written_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTagWriteError(NFCWriteException exception) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        //TODO translate exeptions
        Toast.makeText(context, exception.getType().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a dialog while waiting for the tag
     * @return
     */
    public AlertDialog createWaitingDialog(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(dialogViewId, null, false);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_nfc_black_48dp);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.wait_write_dialog_title)
        .setView(view)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               nfcManager.undoWriteText();
           }
       });
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Any one?

Answer (score 0):

You must check Action of Intent of your launch activity against tag type you are listening (defined by Intent filter in manifest).
For example:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if(i.getAction() == NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
{
    //runYourMethod();
}
```

use your tag type:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html

Comment: Can you please give me more information? i already read the android developer but still not get it.